# Even offset while scaling edges?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make these edges scale evenly but they're not. I tried using inset but inset only applies to things going inwards and not extrude stuff.
[image]

Comment: moonboots answer looks good so i'm not sure what exactly you want. can you make a drawing to show how you want it to look like?

Comment: Is there an even scale method? Moonboots' answer is a bit too much work.

Comment: @NewBlenderer "Scaling" in geometry is always a multiplication by a factor, so there is no even scaling if the dimensions are not even in all directions. I guess what you want is offsetting the edge (see my answer below).

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Check my answer, there's no need for extruding.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann +1 thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the following doesn't work, it might be that you don't have the *Mesh Tools* add-on enabled which comes with Blender. If so, go to *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Add-ons*, search for *Edit Mesh Tools* and enable it.

1. Select the bottom edge that you want to extrude.
2. From the *Edge* menu select *Offset Edges* > *Extrude* or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the *Edge* context menu.

[image: edge menu]

3. In the tool options you can set the *Width*.

[image: offset width]

4. If you want, you can also set an angle, either choose one from the 15° steps below or enter a free value. Be aware that if you set for example a width of 0.5 m, the object gets 1 m wider and longer if you extrude flat (at an angle of 0°), but less if you use a different angle since the width is the overall length of the edge, not the distance in X or Y direction regardless of the angle.

[image: angle]

Comment: Thank you. This is what i was looking for!!

Comment: I would like to add.... This solves so many problems man!! Wow!

Comment: @NewBlenderer If you don't want a straight or flat offset but don't need a specific angle, you could use _Depth_. This way you can say, I want to extrude the edge 1 m outwards and 0.5 m down for example. In this case (other than using _Angle_) the shape gets 1 m larger in all directions. But there are also quite different results depending on if you have _Follow Face_ enabled or not for example. The best is to play around with this tool and try to understand how it works.

Comment: Yes, i did play around with the variety of options that are avaiable. And they offer so much control. It is a life saver.

Comment: @NewBlenderer Now this is off-topic to your question, but check out the Inset Tool as well. I see many tutorials where people do so much with extruding and scaling and then tweaking because it didn't scale evenly... the Inset Tool works much better in many cases and most times it can be used instead of extruding and scaling or extruding along normals.

Comment: Exactly, specially when you want to make a non square or non circular container and you want the base to be smaller than the top. I agree.

Comment: @NewBlenderer Or even larger, depending on your mesh - the Inset Tool has an "outset" option as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK so now that *Edge Offset* exists, I guess Gordon Brinkmann's answer is more convenient   ;)

Old solution, extrude down your shape:

[image]

Select the face ring:

[image]

Extrude faces along normals:

[image]

Remove the bottom:

[image]

Comment: Yes I did that. But I want a solution to this weird problem. And I am sure I am not the only one.

Comment: @moonboots Just use _Offset Edges_?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann oh ok I didn't know it existed  ;)

Comment: @moonboots That's what I suspected, but I wasn't sure if you would look into this question again after answering 

Comment: Yes thanks for warning me, it looks pretty recent

Comment: @moonboots It's the _Edit Mesh Tools_ add-on which is available in Blender since 2.90 (before it was an external add-on) and it has many other features that make mesh editing much easier.

Comment: ooh ok thanks, I had it enabled but didn't know, I wonder why it's not by default, like many others (Node Wrangler or LoopTools)